# What iOS layers Foundation and Core Foundation frameworks belong to?

Tags: ios, architecture

iOS is a layered architecture that has the following layers:

- Cocoa Touch
- Media
- Core Services
- Core OS

My question is in what layers Foundation and Core Foundation frameworks reside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both part of the [Core Services layer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html).

Comment: The link is for the Mac architecture, but it's basically the same as iOS, at least on what you question is about